# Pull numbers out of a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal

Okay so, I have a column that looks something like this:

```
 20140813000000000
```

It is displaying a date, in the format of `decimal(17,0)`, but I need to take the first 8 characters out of it to convert it to a date so it can be used. I've tried `casting` and `converting` and `substring` but everything leads to an arithmetic overflow. Any help on getting that date out?

Example of what I am using and the error:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST([tblDate] as varchar),1,8) as Date)

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I tried the following: SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(20140813000000000 AS VARCHAR),1,8) AS DATE); and it worked fine.  So I am guessing there is some specific value in your table that causes the problem?

Comment: @rich but using which database? Maybe it doesn't work on his db

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Agreed, knowing the type of database involved is key here.  I guessed it was SQL Server from the look of the syntax, but I could be wrong?

Comment: It is probably the 0's, there are multiple 0's in the column along with values like these.

Comment: Yar, if you run this: SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(00000000000000000 AS VARCHAR(17)), 1, 8) AS DATE); it generates the error you saw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, I added a case to filter out the 0's to NULL before casting it as a date:

```
Select
    CAST(CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST([tblDate] as varchar),1,8) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE SUBSTRING(CAST([tblDate] as varchar),1,8)
    END as DATE)
```

Comment: To add some syntactic sugar: `SELECT CAST(NULLIF(LEFT(CAST([tblDate] AS varchar(17)), 8), '00000000') AS date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Great that you found a solution to your own problem, but note that this won't work if you ever have values like 00000000000000001 in your table as this will be converted to 1, pass the first test in your CASE statement and then throw an exception as 1 won't CAST to DATE.

This is more long-winded, but safer... (full example included):

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE ([tblDate] NUMERIC(17,0));
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES(00000000000000001); --Edge case
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES(20140831000000001); --Value to parse
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(RIGHT('00000000000000000' + CAST([tblDate] AS VARCHAR(17)), 17), SPACE(1), '0'), 1, 8) = '00000000' THEN NULL 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(CAST([tblDate] AS VARCHAR(17)), 1, 8) 
    END
FROM 
    @TestTable;
```

Returns:

```
NULL
2014-08-31
```

Your answer would throw an exception for the first value.

If you are sure your data will ALWAYS either be all zeroes or contain a date to be parsed then fine...